# SQL WordPress Custom Query Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm having some difficulty with my SQL statement. I'm doing a query on WordPress to display posts based on multiple post meta fields. When I do the query and filter with only one meta field, or a OR on multiple it works, however AND on multiple fails.

```
SELECT wposts . *
FROM wp_posts wposts
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT post_id
  FROM wp_postmeta wpostmeta
  WHERE (
    (wpostmeta.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_industry'
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Legal Services')
    AND (
    wpostmeta.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_province'
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'New Brunswick')
  )
  GROUP BY post_id
) 
AS t ON t.post_id = wposts.ID
WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wposts.post_type = 'business'
ORDER BY wposts.post_title ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: OR and AND are logically different.  what results do you expect?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I want AND, I want to filter both meta values. I can confirm the data exists, however my statement is not returning that.

Comment: What is your question? What *should* your query look like? Post what you tried, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: The OP is trying to figure out how he can get the set of posts that have both an industry meta key of 'Legal Services' AND a province meta_key of 'New Brunswick'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is testing if meta_key (and meta_value) is 2 different values in the same row, which is impossible. But I see what you are trying to do..

Try joining the wp_postmeta table twice except each with an ON clause that excludes all rows except those that satisfy the meta_key condition:

```
SELECT 
    p.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(pm.meta_key,':',pm.meta_value) SEPARATOR ',') AS meta_values
FROM 
    wp_posts p
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_bi ON (pm_bi.post_id = p.ID AND pm_bi.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_industry')
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_bp ON (pm_bp.post_id = p.ID AND pm_bp.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_province')
WHERE 
    pm_bi.meta_value = 'Legal Services'
    AND pm_bp.meta_value = 'New Brunswick'
    AND p.post_type = 'business'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY p.post_title ASC
```

Note: I joined the wp_postmeta table 3 times here to help prove that the conditions are satisfied, but you can remove the GROUP_CONCAT line (and the comma on the previous line of course) and the first JOIN to wp_postmeta and the query will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery, it looks like it's looking for records where both `wpostmeta.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_industry'` and `wpostmeta.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_province'` -- in other words, `wpostmeta.meta_key` needs to be equal to two strings simultaneously to satisfy this condition.  Also, it's looking for `wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Legal Services'` and `wpostmeta.meta_value = 'New Brunswick'`.

My guess is that this is what you want in the `WHERE` clause of the subquery -- change one of the `AND`s to an `OR`:

```
....
WHERE (
  (wpostmeta.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_industry'
    AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Legal Services')
  OR ( -- changed to an OR
  wpostmeta.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_province'
    AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'New Brunswick')
)
....
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch. Answering a question is hard enough, finding the question yourself is even harder.

Comment: The OP explicitly stated that he already finds that it works with OR, but he is trying to figure out how he can get the set of posts that have both an industry meta key of 'Legal Services' AND a province meta_key of 'New Brunswick'.

Comment: @ghbarratt -- actually, it's not clear what the OP wants.  It states that he did `OR` on something, and that it worked ... but what was it?  However, the posted code clearly MUST return no results for the reason I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the where clause of your inner select; I'm guessing wpostmeta returns MULTIPLE rows.  A previous comment that a string can't be two values is correct.  The 2nd approach should work if the 1st doesn't

**at first I thought**

```
WHERE
  ((wpostmeta.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_industry' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Legal Services') OR 
   (wpostmeta.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_province' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'New Brunswick'))
Group by Post_ID
HAVING count(post_ID) = 2
```

This will work ONLY if there is only one record in the wpostmeta for each type of entry.  If 
postmeta.meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_industry' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Legal Services' can occur twice, then the above does't work.

**2nd approach**

```
Select wposts.*
FROM WP_Posts wposts
INNER JOIN  (
Select POST_ID from WP_POSTMeta where meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_industry' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Legal Services'
INTERSECT
SELECT POST_ID FROM WP_POST_META WHERE meta_key = 'ulnooweg_business_province' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'New Brunswick'
) 
AS T on T.Post_ID = wposts.ID
```